# Understanding MA protocol as a variant of TM for small space setting

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, interactive-proofs, machine-models

MA protocol is one of the most basic models of interactive proofs.

Merlin is a prover sending a witness $w$ for given input string $x$, and Arthur is a verifier  who verifies if $w$ is a positive witness of $x$ using  random bits $r$.  We say that $L$ is decided by MA protocol $\mathcal{P}$, if the following two conditions hold.

1. $x\in L\Rightarrow \exists w\,\Pr_r[\mathcal{P}(x,w,r)=1]>2/3$,
2. $x\notin L\Rightarrow \forall w\,\Pr_r[\mathcal{P}(x,w,r)=1]<1/3$.

> My question is:  What is the formal description of Turing Machine exactly simulating MA protocol with space $S(n)$?

Comment: (1) and (2) together imply that $\: L = \{\} \;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I don’t really understand the question. Do you want to ask what class we get from MA if we further impose a space restriction? And anyway, what *is* the space of the protocol? Is it the space used by Arthur’s computation? Does it include $w$? Does it include $r$?